# Finding unique solutions to simultaneous equations using matrices.

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

Question: When does the system have a unique solution?

\begin{cases}
kx + 3y = -6\\
x + (k+2)y = 2
\end{cases}

I've been showed questions similar to this, I've attempted to construct this into multiple matrices whereby $AX=B$, but get lost due to the $k$ variable.

Any help to get the ball rolling appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have the system in the form of ${\rm A} \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{b}$

$$\begin{bmatrix} k & 3 \\ 1 & k+2 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{-6 \\ 2} $$

which is invertible when ${\rm det}({\rm A}) = k^2+2k-3 \neq 0$, or when $k \neq 1$ and $k \neq -3$.

The solution is

$$ \pmatrix{x \\ y} = \begin{bmatrix} k & 3 \\ 1 & k+2 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \pmatrix{-6 \\ 2} = \tfrac{1}{k^2+2k-3} \begin{bmatrix} k+2 & -3 \\ -1 & k \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{-6 \\ 2} = \pmatrix{ \tfrac{6}{1-k} \\ \tfrac{2}{k-1} } $$

Comment: The answer by @user376343 is the more correct answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Determinant of the coefficient matrix ${\rm A}$ is
\begin{align*}
{\rm det}({\rm A})= \left|\begin{matrix}
k & 3\\
1 & k + 2
\end{matrix}\right|=(k-1)(k+3)
\end{align*}
It is necessarily nonzero, as the system has unique solution.
In this case is [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) appropriate. For each $\; k\neq 1, k\neq -3,\;$ the solution is the pair
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{{\rm det}({\rm A_x})}{{\rm det}({\rm A})},\frac{{\rm det}({\rm A_y})}{{\rm det}({\rm A})}\right),$$
where
\begin{align*}
{\rm det}({\rm A_x})= \left|\begin{matrix}
-6 & 3\\
2 & k + 2
\end{matrix}\right|
\quad \text{and} \quad 
{\rm det}({\rm A_y})= \left|\begin{matrix}
k & -6\\
1 & 2
\end{matrix}\right|.
\end{align*}